# Set-DistributionGroup -GrantSendOnBehalfTo does not seem to be working

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

The setup is simple: Exchange 2010 with Outlook 2010 clients. I've setup a distribution group to include the CEO's secretaries and have used

```
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity secretary-group@example.com -GrantSendOnBehalfTo secretary1@example.com
```

However the option to change the From: field does not appear in the Outlook 2010 of secretary1. Have I misunderstood something about [-GrantSendOnBehalfTo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124955.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set permissions on distribution groups, only on security groups.  Some posts on technet's social forums indicate that the "proper way" to do this is to individually set the GrantSendOnBehalfTo to the individual user mailboxes, not the distribution group itself.

Comment: [Set-DistributonGroup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124955.aspx), according to its manual: "Use the Set-DistributionGroup cmdlet to modify the settings of an existing distribution group". And in the -GrantSendOnBehalfTo it does not say anything particular to Security Groups only.